Scala : create dataframe column from array where the array size is variable
I have a variable like
val activityId = "activity_" + activityNum + "_id"

the variable activityNum is incremented from a loop (1,2,3,...)
so I want to create an array where it can be like
array_activityId = array(col("activity_1_id"),col("activity_2_id"),col("activity_3_id"),...)

and then modify a df by adding the array as column
val wellnessActivity1 =  wellnessActivity.withColumn("activityIds",array_activityId)

Can any one provide the code that can do so?
Tried to create an array but no success

It's unclear what you're asking. Can you clarify which part you're having an issue with? What did you try? What didn't work so far?

@bennani-med - you'll need to provide some actual runnable code for people to help.  If those columns already exist then functions.array is the correct thing to use, so the problem lies elsewhere.  You haven't provided code or the actual issue (just "no success") so you are unlikely to get help.
